# Cordova Share via WhatsApp from a click inside WebView

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webview, whatsapp

I've my app built with Cordova (5.5.1) and I'm trying to share Url's via WhatsApp.
I'm using the following protocol: `whatsapp://send?text= test`

If I open my website on a mobile browser it's working. On iOS it's working as well.

I've tried to add this `<access origin="whatsapp:*" launch-external="yes" />` to my config.xml but it still not working.

I'm using InAppBrowser and this is how I'm opening my webview

`var ref = window.open("http://m.estadao.com.br/?load-all=true", "_blank", "location=no", "toolbar=no", "closebuttoncaption=a", "EnableViewPortScale=no");`

Here is the error: [image: error cordova whatsapp]

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: It's not clear to me. First you open your website on inAppBrowser and the web you open has whatsapp links?

Comment: @jcesarmobile exactly

Comment: @jcesarmobile same error appearing on my side as well. I have opened my website using inappbrowser for android. it has addtoany social media sharing icons and whatsapp is showing this error

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla, so you are using InAppBrowser, so what I said for the other question doesn't apply, that's for inside the Cordova webview. As I said, better create your own question and provide more information, such as that you are using InAppBrowser and that happens when the website has social media buttons, and an example of what those buttons do might be helpful too

Comment: Ok sure @jcesarmobile. I will do soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic InAppBrowser on Android doesn't navigate to custom Url Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51908666/ionic-inappbrowser-on-android-doesnt-navigate-to-custom-url-scheme)

Comment: Whose looking for answer please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53502532/3260012

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it editing the core of plugin InAppBrowser.java

Changed this

```
else if (url.startsWith("geo:") || url.startsWith(WebView.SCHEME_MAILTO) || url.startsWith("market:")){
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                LOG.e(LOG_TAG, "Error with " + url + ": " + e.toString());
            }
        }
```

to

```
else if (url.startsWith("geo:") || url.startsWith(WebView.SCHEME_MAILTO) || url.startsWith("market:") || url.startsWith("whatsapp:"))  {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                LOG.e(LOG_TAG, "Error with " + url + ": " + e.toString());
            }
        }
```

It's important to add this `<access origin="whatsapp:*" launch-external="yes" />` in your config.xml as well.

Comment: +vbotio I think you should mark your answer as the accepted one (the green V shaped icon). This is the same solution I've found to the same problem that was happening with an Android App trying to open Whatsapp from within a WebView.

Comment: This solution not working for me even after editing the ' InAppBrowser.java' file.

Comment: It didn't helped me as well i have applied both changes mentioned

Comment: It didnt work for me too.... Any solution? I am trying to load whatsapp custom schema "whatsapp://" from in-app-browser. Where the link is on loaded page.

Comment: @SD can you provide more details about your problem ?

Comment: Sure. It was same as question. The webpage, that is being called in ionic webview has WhatsApp message send link. It works fine on mobile browser. But didn't work on ionic webview. It was solved using custom scheme.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly in my case, actually @vbotio you should create a pull request onto the inappbrowser git project IMHO. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: @nnimis can you please add your code from the Ionic / Cordova side ? how your opening the custom URL schema ?

Comment: @Vasanth I haven't yet implemented it on the Cordova side, it needs to be implemented on Android code (by changing app/java/org.apache.cordova/InAppBrowser.java as described on the solution)

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that, you need to trigger that from Cordova /Ionic right ?  Ex: cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options); I wanted to know that piece of code