# Start whatsapp from webview

Tags: android, webview, whatsapp

I have an app that loads a newspaper site in a webview. In that site you can share a news in facebook, twitter and whatsapp. I have facebook's and twitter's links covered with

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading()
```

I can't figer out how to launch the whatsapp app. It uses a custom URL scheme:

```
whatsapp://send?text=
```

I get: the webpage at whatsapp://send?text= could not be loaded because:

```
net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Comment: This may help you: [Cordova Share via WhatsApp from a click inside WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31880492/3110234)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using loop from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242230/launch-custom-android-application-from-webview) question: using `Intent.ACTION` would give You best results.

Answer (score 4):

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.startsWith("tel:") || url.contains("https://wa.me/")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `wa.me` as a domain for sharing texts on whatsapp.  Just test this URL here yourself: http://wa.me/?text=mytest.  I see:

> ERROR
>
> PAGE NOT FOUND

Don't use the `wa.me` domain.  Use the `api.whatsapp.com` domain.  `wa.me` requires that you use a phone number.  Well, typically, you want the share URL to be shared to *other people* that *the user* knows, so, you'd want to leave that blank.  Check it out...

> [https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere](https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere&phone=123)
>
> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere&phone=123

Works for me!  Hope this helps someone out there!

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#whatsapp

[image: Social Share URLs]

Answer (score 0):

be sure to have a proper URL encoded string after `text=`

Answer (score 0):

I've just found that it is possible to open a conversation to a number [Using Click to Chat](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000030)

> To create your own link with a pre-filled message that will
>   automatically appear in the text field of a chat, use
>   `https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber/?text=urlencodedtext` where
>   whatsappphonenumber is a full phone number in international format and
>   URL-encodedtext is the URL-encoded pre-filled message.

Example:`https://wa.me/15551234567?text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale`

**NOTE:** It opens WhastApp application if you click the link using a mobile phone browser (at least from Android)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url != null && url.startsWith("https://wa.me")) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url.replace("+",""))));

                return true;

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```