# Ionic InAppBrowser on Android doesn't navigate to custom Url Scheme

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, inappbrowser

I am having a setup, where I open a url in the plugin InAppBrowser with target '_blank'. The plugin Deeplinks is also installed and configured.

```
const browser: InAppBrowserObject = this.iab.create(url, '_blank', <InAppBrowserOptions>{
    location: "no",
    toolbar: "no",
    footer: "no"
});

browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((event: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
    console.log(event);

    if (event.url.indexOf('wflwr://payment/success') > -1) {
        browser.close();
    }

    if (event.url.indexOf('wflwr://payment/cancel') > -1) {
        browser.close();
    }

    if (event.url.indexOf('wflwr://payment/error') > -1) {
        browser.close();
    }
});
```

I shortened it to show just the important parts. The url which is opened is https://www.voan.ch/wfl/ (it is just a Mock before the real implementation)

The expected behaviour is, that on a click on each of the links on the url, the browser instance inside the app should close. This works as intended on iOS, but not on Android. The event is just not triggered. If I change one of the urls to e.g. `<a href="https://www.google.com">CANCEL</a>`, then the Event gets triggered.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ? In certain case, it's working for me if I use "loadstop" event

Comment: No. It seems like InAppBrowser doesn't support Custom Url Scheme properly. We switched to normal https Url Scheme

Answer (score 3):

the support for this was added in latest [pr](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/263)

to use it you will need 2 things:

for example to allow whatsapp custom scheme and twitter

- add new config.xml preference with the custom schemes you want to support:

  `` <preference name="AllowedSchemes" value="whatsapp,twitter" />` ``
- add event listeners customscheme:

  `inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('customscheme', function (event) {
          //do whatever you want here like:
           window.open(event.url, "_system");
      });`

Comment: We switched to https, so I cannot test it. Can somebody confirm it works like that, then I will mark it as the right answer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but nothing happening. My app with custom URL schema is not opening, there is no error as well.